# Can I take a bicycle on the ferry from Palermo (Sicily) to Genoa (Italy)?

Tags: italy, ferries, bicycles, sicily, genoa

I would like to take a touring bicycle on the ferry from Palermo (Sicily Italy) to Genoa (Italy). The bicycle is a touring bicycle, i.e. fully assembled, cannot be folded and has bags on the front and rear luggage racks.

The site of the ferry operator GNV https://www.gnv.it/en also has no information on passengers with a bicycle.

On this site http://www.sncm.co.uk/index.htm for the route Palermo-Genoa, under the option "vehicle" I cannot select bicycle (only foot passage).

[image]

[image]

However, as an exemple, for the route Palermo-Livorno the option "bicycle" is available. This leads me to suspect that bicycles are not allowed on the ferry Palermo-Genoa

[image]

Comment: Not specific to Italy, but the fact that one has an option for bicycle and the other doesn't may simply mean that booking or an additional fee is required for carrying a bicycle on one route and no bookings are needed on the other. Some may require booking, others operate "first come first served" (total bans seem very rare). Policies on booking vary greatly between ferry companies and routes in the examples here: https://www.discoverferries.com/bike-ferry-holiday/

Comment: Seems like it's a good time to look for the "Contact Us" link on the ticketing site and ask them. That's the best way to get a 100% correct answer. If they tell you to book it as a "Foot Passenger" and that you'll be fine, be sure to _print out_ a copy of the emailed response _and_ have an electronic copy available as well, just to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

I asked info@gnv.it

> Can I take a bicycle on the ferry from Palermo to Genoa?
>
> Posso prendere una bicicletta sul traghetto da Palermo a Genova?

Here the answer from the ferry operator GNV [www.gnv.it](http://www.gnv.it)

> Good morning from GNV,
>
> further to your kind request, we are pleased to inform you that
> bicycles can be embarked free of charge on condition that they are not
> transported on other vehicles (cars, motor caravans etc.) exceeding
> the dimensions of the vehicle category booked.
>
> If you are travelling with bicycles only, no booking is required.
>
> If you load the bikes on the roof or the back of your car, overall
> length and height must be taken into account when selecting the
> corresponding vehicle category.
>
> Please do not hesitate to contact us for any further information you
> may require.
>
> Thank you for travelling with us.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Grandi Navi Veloci S.p.A.
>
> Via Balleydier 7, 16149 - GENOVA T +39-010/2094.591 F +39-010/2094.225
>
> info@gnv.it [www.gnv.it](http://www.gnv.it)